# setExposureCompensation does not work in samsung galaxy s3

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

```
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

params.setExposureCompensation(progress + camera.getParameters().getMinExposureCompensation());
camera.setParameters(params);
```

I have set setExposureCom[ensation values in samsung s3 and it is not work but when i tested this code in other mobile micromax its run perfectly
please guide what is problem in the samsung galaxy s3?

Comment: when you execute this line of code, will S3 return any related error/warning log outputs?

Comment: I encountered a problem with the S3 where the "setExposureCompensation" works, but not for all min-max range. The range I get is -12 to 12, but in practice, values exeeded from -4 to 4 are acting not as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the output of

```
camera.getParameters().getMinExposureCompensation()
```

and

```
camera.getParameters().getMaxExposureCompensation()
```

to make sure that your device actually supports different exposure compensation settings before setting it.

You should set progress to:

```
camera.getParameters().getExposureCompensationStep()
```

to make sure that you set a valid exposureCompensation.